# PHP OOP: how to use a generic MySQL class in other classes

Tags: php, mysql, oop, class

I've just started using OOP PHP and ran into a question. I've set up a generic mysql class that allows me to connect to a database and has some functions to obtain records from a table:

```
class mysql{
    //some lines to connect, followed by:
    public function get_record($sql)
    {
      $result = mysql_result(mysql_query($sql));
      return $result;
      //obiously it's a bit more advanced, but you get the picture.

    }
}
```

Next, I have a class to obtain user details:

```
class user{
    __construct($id)
    {  
        $this->id = $id
    }
    public function get_username($id)
    {
         $username = get_record("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = '".$this->id."'");
         return $username;
    }
}
```

I tried this, but got the error that the function get_record was unkown. I solved this by adding $mysql = new mysql(); to the user class.

However, it feels quite inefficient to have to instantiate the mysql object for every class that uses my database methods (that's pretty much all of them).

Is there a way to make the mysql class and its methods accessible to all other classes, without having to call the mysql class in every method?

Comment: Please, don't create MySQL classes. There are too many of those around, even when PHP has such a thing built-in already. It's called PDO (PHP Database Objects). PDO is transferable to other developers, while having to figure out someone else's MySQL-class again and again feels pretty pointless.

Answer (score 6):

For one, you don't need to use singleton in this case - or actually, you almost never do. See [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/scottdensmore/archive/2004/05/25/140827.aspx), for example.

Second, I think your OO designs are a bit off. The main point of object-oriented programming and design is to isolate responsibility into separate classes. Right now, you're giving your User class two main responsibilities - store / carry one user's relevant data, and query the data service (in this case, a simple MySQL / database abstraction layer).

You should first move that functionality into a separate object. Usually, this is called a Service - so in this case, it's a `UserService`. A `UserService` has one responsibility: provide access to `User` objects. So it'd sorta look like this:

```
class UserService {
    public function __construct($mysql); // uses the mysql object to access the db. 
    public function get($id) {
        $result = $this->mysql->get_record("select x from y");
        $user = new User($result['id'], $result['name']); // assuming user has a constructor that takes an id and a name
        return $user;
    }
    public function save($user);
    public function delete($user);
}
```

You tie it all together at the start of your request (or where you need to access users):

```
$mysql = new MySQL($credentials);
$service = new UserService($mysql);
$user = $service->find(1337);
```

It's not perfect, but it's a much neater design. Your MySQL object does what it needs to do (build a connection, execute queries), your user object is plain dumb, and your service does only one thing, i.e. provide a layer between the actual storage layer and the thing calling it.

Comment: +1 This is a great design!  User objects should have one responsibility, to hold user data.

Comment: This is the best way of doing this! This is a really good advise. Even better would be with usage of interface, but it is good enough. Testable, clean. thumbs up

Comment: I have been looking for a simple way to explain the best method of communicating with a database. The only difference between approaches here is that I have been using a controller instead of service class. However, now I have seen this, I think I can still use my controller and separate functionality to the service.

Answer (score 2):

Design your mysql class to be called statically:

```
$username = Mysql::get_record("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = '".$this->id."'");
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php

Comment: I'd rather call it `Mysql::get_record("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = %d",$this->id);`

Comment: There are definitely many improvements the OP can make. My answer deals with the narrow question of avoiding incessant instantiation.

Answer (score 2):

This is a common problem, and so there is a common solution to this.
As you might know, in software development common solutions on common problems are called Design Patterns.

There are two design patterns that can help you solve this problem.
In a more abstract sense the problem you are facing is:

> *How can i make class A available in class B?*

**The Singleton pattern**

> "In the singleton pattern a class can distribute one instance of itself to other classes."

This is not exactly what you are looking for, as your website may use multiple database connections. However, it is used by a lot of people in this way.

Read some information about using a singleton class as a database provider here:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/os-php-designptrns/#N10124

More information on the singleton pattern in PHP: 
http://www.fluffycat.com/PHP-Design-Patterns/Singleton/

Another sensible approach is the registry pattern:

**Registry Pattern**

You can find information about the registry pattern on the link below, as well as an implementation almost identical that you are looking for:
http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/php-patterns-part/

Even more powerful is a combination between the singleton and the registry.

Good luck and enjoy learning OOP PHP!

Comment: Actually, the singleton pattern is, in this particular case, not really needed - after all, anything that doesn't do anything with a database connection doesn't need to have access to that class, and by using singleton, your whole application gets access to singleton. Same goes for registry, although it's a slightly better alternative. No, I'd say that a database interaction object is a service, and services can be assigned to objects that need them, for example by using the dependency injection pattern. See: http://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html

Comment: @Cthulhu - You're comment about using the singleton pattern is not needed for this problem is correct, however it is a common used solution to this specific problem.
Personally, i am not very familiar with dependency injection, but thank you for pointing it out. Will look into it.

Comment: +1 for dependency injection... it makes unit testing so much easier if you don't have globals all over the place, instead injecting what you need into your class. And yes, both registry and singleton are globals too... just more disguised.

Comment: A singleton is just a global variable in disguise.  Do not teach new programmers to use bad practices.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass in the mysql object to each user object.  So it would look like this:

```
$mysql = new mysql();
$user = new user( $mysql, $id);
$name = $user->get_username();

class user {
    public function __construct($mysql, $id) {
        $this->mysql = $mysql;
        $this->id = $id;
    }
    public function get_username() {
        $username = $this->mysql->get_record("SELECT name FROM users WHERE id = '".$this->id."'");
        return $username;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

using global variables, although that is probably not the best option.

```
$mysql = new mysql();

function someFunction() {
  global $mysql;
  $mysql->get_record(...)
}
```

or a static method for your mysql class (see [Singleton](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.patterns.php#language.oop5.patterns.singleton))

```
class mysql {
  public static $theInstance = new mysql();
  public static function getInstance() {
    return $this->theInstance;
  }
}

function someFunction() {
  $database= mysql::getInstance();
  $database->get_record(...)
}
```

Comment: Uh, please don't suggest to use globales!

Answer (score 0):

Start to think to use Doctrine, it's better

http://www.doctrine-project.org/